# visual studio 2012 lightswitch HTML Project error can't load application item provider sequence contains no element

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

It is the first time for me to use lightswitch and when trying to start a new Lightswitch HTML project on Visual Studio Pro 2012 I get the following error:

***cannot load application item provider sequence contains no element This may indicate the model file is corrupted***
and vs crash
I tried reinstalling the update from Microsoft and also repaired VS and still getting this error

I tried running Lightswitch desktop app and it works fine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Solved
The Problem found conflict between LightSwitch and Resharper I upgraded Resharper to the latest version and it worked fine

Comment: How did you figure out that they were conflicting? I'm getting the same error, but I don't have resharper. Wondering if it is conflicting with one of my other extensions.

Comment: Resharper was the problem in my case too. Disabling it temporarily worked as well...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even after uninstalling Resharper. Uninstalling the TeamCity Visual Studio Plugin did the trick for me.